# Lighttpd ending slash url issue

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

Here is my rewrite on conf

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/([^/\.]+)/?$" => "/post.php?p=$1"
)
```

I need http://nullfix.com/digisales/ and http://nullfix.com/digisales to work both with or without slash at the end can it be done?

What Am i doing wrong im bad on regex stuff... please help!

Comment: Im an idiot i have on my html relative paths to css and stuff thats why i don't see the css when i view the site with slash in the end with some mods on html seems now to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the caret `^` from the begining of the regex:

```
"/([^/\.]+)/?$" => "/post.php?p=$1"
```